# Regex for non-consecutive uppercase with lowercase

Tags: c++, regex

```
std::string s("AAA");
std::smatch m;
std::regex e("(?=.{3,}[A-Z])(?=.{0,}[a-z]).*");
output = std::regex_search(s, m, e);
```

Here it should have 3 or more uppercase letters and zero or more lowercase letter.
However the output is zero meaning it fails. When I try replace zero with 1 and
s("AAA4") it works fine.

So now I want it to allow zero or more but it seems like it is not accepting zero
I even tried quantifier (*) which is equivalent to {0,} still not working.

Here is an example:

```
string1 "AAA"
string2 "AAAb"
string3 "AbAA"
```

The following regex works with string1 and string2 as the uppercase are consecutive:

```
[A-Z]{3,}[a-z]*
```

The following regex works with string2 and string3 but it will not work when there are no lowercase even though I specified 0.

```
(?=.{3,}[A-Z])(?=.{0,}[a-z]).*
```

What I am looking for is a regex to work with all of them with following cases:

- Allow 0 or more occurrence of lowercase
- Validate 3 uppercase in string but they dont have to be consecutive like string 3

Comment: Are you looking for `std::regex e("(?:[^A-Z]*[A-Z]){3}");` to check if   a string that has 3 uppercase ASCII letters?

Comment: This does work, thanks, but I need to consider lowercase too in regex as I send then number of occurrence as a input to function.

Comment: What do you mean? What number of occurrences? Please add only relevant details to the question. When you say there can be 0+ lowercase letters, it sounds as if you just do not care if there are any in the string.

Comment: (?=.{3,}[A-Z])(?=.{0,}[a-z]).* in this regex I send 3 for uppercase and zero for lowercase as variables so how can this be done as it works fine except when given zero.

Comment: Good, that makes more sense now.

Comment: Why use a regex? Why not just iterate once over the string and count how many uppercase letters there are?

Comment: that is one way of doing it , but actually I am building up the regex using input to function and then display formed regex for future use and modification.

Comment: [std::count_if](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/count) may server better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Here it should have 3 or more uppercase letters and zero or more lowercase letter.

Your [`(?=.{3,}[A-Z])(?=.{0,}[a-z]).*`](https://regex101.com/r/MsivIb/1/) regex matches a part of a line consisting of 0+ chars (`.*`) that starts with any 3 or more chars followed with an uppercase ASCII letter (`(?=.{3,}[A-Z])`), and that has at least one lowercase ASCII letter (`(?=.{0,}[a-z])`).

To match a string that contains *x* uppercase ASCII letters and *y* lowercase ASCII letters, you need to use

```
std::regex e("^(?=(?:[^A-Z]*[A-Z]){x}[^A-Z]*$)(?=(?:[^a-z]*[a-z]){y}[^a-z]*$)");
                                   ^                              ^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/RvMylF/2)

**Details**:

- `^` - start of a string
- `(?=(?:[^A-Z]*[A-Z]){x}[^A-Z]*$)` - Positive lookahead 1 that is triggered at the start of the string and checks if there are *x* sequences of

  - `[^A-Z]*` - zero or more chars other than uppercase ASCII letters
  - `[A-Z]` - an uppercase ASCII letter
  - `[^A-Z]*$` - zero or more chars other than uppercase ASCII letters up to the end of the string (`$`)
- `(?=(?:[^a-z]*[a-z]){y}[^a-z]*$)` - Positive lookahead 2 that is *also* triggered at the start of the string (as lookaheads are zero-width assertions) and checks if there are *y* sequences of

  - `[^a-z]*` - zero or more chars other than lowercase ASCII letters
  - `[a-z]` - an lowercase ASCII letter
  - `[^a-z]*$` - zero or more chars other than lowercase ASCII letters up to the end of the string.

Comment: This works great and the explanation is excellent thanks for that. Just something is missing in the question I was using a range for x and y like {3,} and I tried that in your regex but it doesnt apply to it. Example {3,5} for uppercase letters and enter more than five it accepted it which is wrong.

Comment: Ok, got it, you need to add a bit to the pattern.

Comment: Thanks for your help

Answer (score -1):

```
^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.{3,}[A-Z]).+$
```

**Explanation:**

```
^                  // the start of the string
(?=.*[a-z])        // use positive look ahead to see if at least one lower case letter exists
(?=.{3,}[A-Z])     // use positive look ahead to see if at least 3 upper case letter exists
.+                 // gobble up the entire string
$
```

Comment: This doesn't work when string is 'AAA' as (?=.*[a-z]) must have at least one lower case letter

Comment: The `(?=.{3,}[A-Z])` is not correct, and its explanation is wrong. It checks if there is 1 uppercase letter after any 3 or more chars.