# How to use regex to match Uppercase words that are non-consecutive duplicates of lowercase words else where in a file

Tags: python, regex, bash, grep, regex-lookarounds

I am a noob to regex and need some help. I have a basic understanding of regex character classes, anchors, and lookarounds but this specific use-case is proving difficult for me.

I am trying to parse an output of a script that runs monthly that outputs a list of users for inventory purposes. I want to use regex to parse the file to match these conditions:

1. Regex to find lower case words that are repeated as Uppercase words. These Uppercase words are not on the same line, are Non-consecutive occurrences, and can be on new lines or else where in the file.
2. I need a regex that is able to display the duplicate upper case matches
3. Another regex that deletes the duplicate upper case matches

Here is an example of the file output I am trying to parse:

```
"hello","2018-11-19","unitelife"
"world","2018-11-09","unitelife"
"foo","2018-11-16","unitelife"
"bar","2018-10-05","unitelife"
"hello123","2018-09-06","unitelife"
"HELLO123","2018-11-18","unitelife"
"FOO","2018-11-20","unitelife"
"WOWMUCHHAPPY","2018-10-20","unitelife"
"suchjoy","2017-11-28","unitelife"
```

The desired matches I am looking for are:

```
HELLO123
FOO
```

I have tried a number of combinations suggested by the referenced URL discussions below but nothing seems to work for me. Either I am trying incorrect combinations or this feature is not possible. In addition, most topics are discussing consecutive words or letters/characters.

- [Regex for non-consecutive upper-case words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20527107/regex-for-non-consecutive-upper-case-words)
- [Regex for non-consecutive upper-case words PART DEUX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20542191/regex-for-non-consecutive-upper-case-words-part-deux)
- [PCRE Regex non-consecutive repeating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43418823/pcre-regex-non-consecutive-repeating)
- [Regex for non-consecutive uppercase with lowercase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42903223/regex-for-non-consecutive-uppercase-with-lowercase)
- [Regex non-consecutive chars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4739395/regex-non-consecutive-chars)

I want to apologize in advanced if this was discussed before or if it has been categorized incorrectly.  Please let me know rather than down voting it so that  I may edit, close, or reclassify the question to meet the standards accordingly.

Sincerely,

A humbly committed student

Comment: What environment are you working with?

Comment: My apologies, I would like to be able to apply this within multiple enviornments if possible. In particular: bash using grep -E, notepad++, and/or python later on.

Comment: Thanks, are the words you're trying to match always surrounded by `"`s, as in the example?

Comment: Yes they are. I was trying to set some anchors based on them with \b and \S and was able to get the first columns to match but nothing past that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the pattern

```
(?sm)^"([a-z\d]+)"(?i)(?=(?:[^\n]*\n)+?"(?=\1")(?-i)[A-Z\d]+")
```

https://regex101.com/r/nM3iBH/2

The idea is, start by being case-sensitive (no `i`), and match the lower-cased string at the beginning of the line inside the quotes. Then, enable the case-*in*sensitive flag, and lookahead for the same string at the beginning of the line inside quotes. Re-enable case sensitivity, and *match* that same string again inside the lookahead, permitting only upper-case letters (and digits).

Note that this (like any regex algorithm for this problem) has `O(N^2)` complexity, because with any match, you need to check the entire remaining substring for the (uppercased) match.

Also note the use of `"`s rather than the `\b`s you were thinking of - using `"`s instead is more precise given this sort of input and will result in significantly fewer steps overall.

The pattern is quite strict, for the sake of reducing steps. Separated out:

- `(?sm)^"([a-z\d]+)"` - Initial flags, capture quoted lower-cased word at the beginning of a line
- `(?i)` - Enable case-insensivity so that the future `\1` backreference will work properly
- `(?=(?:[^\n]*\n)+?"(?=\1")(?-i)[A-Z\d]+")` Big lookahead for:

  - `(?:[^\n]*\n)+` - Match non-newline characters, followed by a newline character
  - `"(?=\1")` Backreference the original matched word inside quotes at the beginning of a line
  - `(?-i)` Re-enable case-sensitivity so the capitalization can be checked
  - `[A-Z\d]+"` - Match capital letters and digits, followed by a `"`

In order to replace the capital word line with the empty string, instead of using a big lookahead, *match* everything between the lower-case word and the upper-case word in a group (so you have two groups, the lower-case word, and everything following it up until the upper-case word), then match the upper-case word, and replace with only the first two groups (thereby replacing out the upper-case word's line):

```
(?sm)^("[a-z\d]+")(?i)((?:[^\n]*\n)*[^\n]*)\n(?=\1)(?-i)"[A-Z\d]+"[^\n]*
```

replace with

```
\1\2
```

(or the equivalent in your environment)

https://regex101.com/r/nM3iBH/3

Note that if you have overlapping matches, you'll have to do this iteratively until no matches remain.

Comment: Awesome work @CertainPerformance! however, when I check the URL it looks like it is matching the lower case, when I am trying to match the uppercase ones to later delete, replace, etc.  I am trying to play with the combination to reverse the results now.  I will see what I can come up with.

Comment: Oh, your title said `to match lower case words` and I ran with it. Given that the upper-case words come *after* the lower-case words, matching the other way around to match uppers instead of lowers would be a whole lot more awkward, because you'd have to look somewhere *backwards* in the string for a match, and such operations are not supported in most regex environments. What about matching *everything* from the lower-case to the upper-case section, then replacing the upper-case substring with the desired replacement?

Comment: I have changed my title, thanks for the correction.  Since I am new to regex, I may be approaching this all wrong. I remember coming across a look ahead and look behind and vice versa but it does start to sound very complicated. Sure, at this point I am open to any suggestions to play around with :)

Comment: Ok, see edit, use a second capturing group instead of lookahead, and replace with `\1\2`

Comment: Thanks for your help @CertainPerformance, this is the closest to what I am looking for.  I am still trying to understand all this and play around with your new edit.  I will keep you posted.

Comment: Great edit @CertainPerformance. This is a huge leap from where I was struggling before. I did notice something interesting in the new edit. When the next word it came across that it found a duplicate of `foo` and `FOO`, it over looked `hello123` and `HELLO123` in-between them since it is matching everything from the next lower case to the next duplicate Uppercase duplicate . I am wondering if additional crazy regexing is necessary or maybe I can just run the regex again after the first output? I am still tinkering around with this. Thanks again everyone for your patience and being so helpful!

Comment: Right, that's why I said `if you have overlapping matches, you'll have to do this iteratively until no matches remain` (same pattern, just keep executing it)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution using just `bash`, with no regular expressions:

```
> cat filter.sh
#!/bin/bash

declare -A lower=()
declare -A upper=()

while IFS= read -r line; do
  eval "words=( $(tr ',' ' ' <<< "$line") )"
  for w in "${words[@]}"; do
    [[ "${w^^}" = "$w" ]] && upper["$w"]=1 || lower["$w"]=1
  done
done

for u in "${!upper[@]}"; do
  exists=${lower["${u,,}"]+foo}
  [[ -n "$exists" ]] && echo "$u"
done
```

There are a couple tricks I'm using here.

First, I'm using associative arrays to weed out repeats. For instance, if `"HELLO123"` appears multiple times in the file, it will only be counted once.

Secondly, I'm parsing the CSV by using `tr` to replace the commas with spaces, and then using `eval` to parse the string into an array, taking advantage of the fact that the individual words are always enclosed in double quotes.

Lastly, I'm using `[[ "${w^^}" = "$w" ]]` as a test to check if a word contains all uppercase letters. The `${w^^}` syntax is a bash-ism that converts a variable to uppercase. I also use `${u,,}` in the second loop, which converts `$u` to lowercase. Note that if you have a word with a mix of uppercase and lowercase letters, it will be counted as a lowercase word. If that doesn't match your expectations, you could change the logic.

The first loop just reads from `stdin`, splits each line into individual words, and then categorizes each word as either uppercase or lowercase. Again, I'm using associative arrays so that each word (regardless of case) only gets counted once.

The second loop just loops through the *keys* of the `upper` associative array (`{${!upper[@]}`), which are just all the uppercase words encountered in the input. For each word, it checks to see if the matching lowercase word was also encountered. The `${lower["${u,,}"]+foo}` syntax is just checking to see if the lowercase word exists in the `lower` array. The `foo` part is just an arbitrary string. You could just as well use `bar` or `exists` or `abc`. This is how you check for the existence of a key in an associative array in `bash`. If the key exists in the array, then the expression will evaluate to `"foo"`, otherwise it will evaluate to an empty string. That's what the subsequent `-n` test is checking for.

Example:

```
> cat input.txt
"hello","2018-11-19","unitelife"
"world","2018-11-09","unitelife"
"foo","2018-11-16","unitelife"
"bar","2018-10-05","unitelife"
"hello123","2018-09-06","unitelife"
"HELLO123","2018-11-18","unitelife"
"FOO","2018-11-20","unitelife"
"WOWMUCHHAPPY","2018-10-20","unitelife"
"suchjoy","2017-11-28","unitelife"

> cat input.txt | ./filter.sh
FOO
HELLO123
```

**NOTE:** Please don't use `eval` in production code. It is prone to all sorts of abuse and mishaps due to unexpected things appearing in the input. For example, consider what would happen if you inserted the following line into the input:

```
"); rm -rf *; foo=("
```

Then `eval` would end up evaluating the string `"words=(); rm -rf *; foo=()"`. Definitely not good. I only used eval here as a quick and dirty way to parse the CSV. There are **much** better (and *safer*) ways to parse CSV in `bash`. The point of this solution is the use of associative arrays to keep track of uppercase and lowercase words, while filtering out duplicates.

**Edit:** Also note that `FOO` and `HELLO123` appear out of order in the output. This is due to the fact that associative arrays don't store the keys in the order in which you created them. So when you do `${!hash[@]}`, it's a crapshoot what order the keys will be in. If that's an issue for you, you could keep a separate regular array to preserve the order.

Comment: Thank you @Mike Holt, I will try the bash method on an isolated server. You bring up a great point though and may have to find a substitution for the eval method since the remote chance of rm -rf occurring on a production server is always a thing to avoid (almost like naming a kid "DROP TABLE students;"). I will play around with this solution as well.

Comment: @unitelife My answer was just a quick and dirty demo of an idea for a general algorithm. I think Python would be better suited for parsing CSV, since it has (probably several) libraries for doing so, and would also be faster reading the input, especially if there's a lot of it. Also, Python `dict`s are much easier to use than `bash` associative arrays.

Answer (score 0):

not with regex but using `awk`s toupper() and tolower() functions

```
$ awk -F, '{lower=tolower($1)} lower==$1 {a[$1];next} 
      toupper($1)==$1 && lower in a{print $1}' file

"HELLO123"
"FOO"
```

if the field is lowercase add to the set, if uppercase and the lowercase is in the set print.

here the order is important (lowercase should appear before the uppercase) as in your example.  If not, need to convert to a two-pass version.  Also easy to remove the quotes if not needed.

Comment: Hello and thank you @karakfa, I have not even thought about awk. I can try and play around with that as well. I will keep you posted on the results.